# Will I eventually finish licking the candy cane?

Tags: achievements, saints-row-iv, saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas

In the ‘How the Saints Save Christmas’ DLC mission, “The Fight Before Christmas”,  an objective gives me the option to 'Go to Stables' or 'Lick Door'.

[image]

I tried licking the candy cane which bars the door, but it seems that this will take forever (although the progress bar appears to move when I mash the <kbd>E</kbd> key).

[image][image][image][image]

I opted to just go to the stables.

I would like to know if it is possible to finish licking the candy cane. If yes, what will happen afterwards? Also, how long will it take? (I'll take an approximation.)

Comment: Ten to fifteen minutes real time, according to a reliable source (a friend of mine who had nothing better to do)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is indeed possible, and you will also get the 'Minty Fresh!' achievement. The text that appears while you are licking it is pretty funny also. You don't get any actual items as far as I know though. After you finish licking (and it does take a long time)

> you find that the door is locked.

Comment: A FU like only the Saints Row dev can deliver :p

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, and took me 5-6 mins. It is kind of like the warden button-mashing thing.. xD